# numpy array split/partition efficiency

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

This appears to be a simple issue, but I've been struggling trying to efficiently split a 2D array:

```
start_time = time.time()
M = np.ones((400,400))

for i in range(10000):
    e = np.array_split(M, 20)
print time.time() - start_time
```

However, this process takes ~6 seconds comparing to ~0.5 seconds when implemented in Mathematica with the **Partition** function, which can become a liability when the array gets much larger. Is there any way for me to speed up the process?

Comment: The `single evaluation of e = np.array_split(M, 20) needs in reality 10000 times less`.
`np.shape(e) is (20, 20, 400) and different from unutbus answer`. He is measuring the mean time for only once calculating M.reshape(20,-1). I get `%timeit Mr=M.reshape(20,-1) 562 ns ± 55.7 ns` and for your case: `%timeit e=np.array_split(M, 20) 93.6 µs ± 4.72 µs`. This is a factor of about 200 slower, but the result is another array than in ubuntus answer, which gives `np.shape(Mr) (20, 8000)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.array_split` may be useful when splitting an array into uneven pieces. Here, the size of each item in `e` is the same, so you could just use [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
e = M.reshape(20,-1)
```

This will be exceedingly fast, since it requires no copying of the array, only a change to the array's shape attribute.

`e` will be a 2D NumPy array of shape (20, 8000), not a list of NumPy arrays.

---

```
In [56]: M = np.ones((400,400))

In [60]: %timeit M.reshape(20,-1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 447 ns per loop
```

Comment: That's incredible! Thanks!! What is the '-1' for, by the way?

Comment: The `-1` in the call to `reshape` tells `reshape` to fill 'er up with whatever number is necessary to use all the items in `M`. Since M has shape (400, 400), there are 160000 items. If the first axis has length 20, then the second axis must have length 160000/20 = 8000. Instead of doing the math, you just put `-1`, and let reshape do the work.